# OpenUI5 Disable/Enable input

Tags: javascript, sapui5, disabled-input

I am using OpenUI5 and I want to disable an input field. I've already tried the following, but it is not working:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("xxx").setDisabled(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The input control does not have a 'disabled' property so the setter setDisabled will not work. However it does have a enabled property so you could use the setEnabled method.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("xxx").setEnabled(false); //Disables the control
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the user from editing the Input value, you should set it's `editable` property to false using the Input's method setEditable(false).